# There are not some files inside the app folder in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am a newbie to Ionic. I just start to build a simple ionic application. But the thing is  there are not some files in the app folder like app.ts , app.html , app.module.ts , app.componenets.ts , main.dev.ts , main.prod.ts .But instead of that I have app.component , app.module , app.scss , main.dev , main.prod .

Can anyone exlpain the reason for that?

Here are some informations

> - cordova CLI : 6.3.1
> - ionic CLI : 2.1.0
> - node.js version : v4.5.0
> - ionic app lib version : 2.0.0-beta.20
> - os : windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the app folder now has only a few files (those that you mentioned) and the rest of the application files live in the 'src' parent folder.

This is a change as of the release candidate version of Ionic2

Comment: Thnaks a lot @Gabe